# How to take two lists as an input and get the output from another two lists with arithmetic operations in between?

Tags: python, list

This is a homework problem. I am just asking about the method to solve this, not the entire solution.

The question as follows:

> Write a Python program to calculate the bill amount to be paid by a
>   customer based on the list of gems and quantity purchased. Any
>   purchase with a total bill amount above Rs.30000 is entitled for 5%
>   discount. If any gem required by the customer is not available in the
>   store, then consider total bill amount to be -1.
>
> Assume that quantity required by the customer for any gem will always
>   be greater than 0. Perform case-sensitive comparison wherever
>   applicable.

I have tried thinking about implementing the program given the inputs below, but can't understand on how to take inputs from list and also do specific arithmetic operations to get the desired output.

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity):
   bill_amount = 0
   # this is the portion where I should write my logic

   return bill_amount

# List of gems available in the store
gems_list = ["Emerald", "Ivory", "Jasper", "Ruby", "Garnet"]

# Price of gems available in the store. gems_list and price_list have one-to-one correspondence
price_list = [1760, 2119, 1599, 3920, 3999]

# List of gems required by the customer
reqd_gems = ["Ivory", "Emerald", "Garnet"]

# Quantity of gems required by the customer. reqd_gems and reqd_quantity have one-to-one correspondence
reqd_quantity = [3, 10, 12]

bill_amount = calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity)
print(bill_amount)
```

Expected result is the total bill amount.

Comment: Why not use a dict instead of 2 lists? `{"gem_name":"amount_needed"}` The question doesn't say you need to use lists specifically

Comment: @Jaba The module in which this question was given has already these lists to work with and I cannot change it, if I do change, the module has a verification system with several test cases and eventually the test cases won't get passed and you cannot submit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally this problem is well suited to using a dictionary, but since this is homework I think your professor wanted you to learn more about traversing lists. Of course, I could be wrong. Anyway, here's a solution without a dictionary

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity):
   bill_amount = 0
   for i in range(len(reqd_gems)):
       ## we walk through every item in reqd_gems
       ## for every item in the list, we assume it's not available until we have found it in gems_list
       itemIsAvailable = False
       for j in range(len(gems_list)):
           # for every item in in reqd_gems, we walk through all the items in gems_list until we find the same item
           if reqd_gems[i] == gems_list[j]:
               itemIsAvailable = True
               # if we have found the same item, then it's available
               bill_amount += price_list[j] * reqd_quantity[i]
               # and we use the fact that the two pairs of lists have 1-to-1 correspondence to calculate the amount to add to bill_amount

       if not itemIsAvailable:
           return -1

   if bill_amount > 30000:
       return bill_amount * 0.95
   return bill_amount
```

Comment: Thanks for the the answer. Yes the learning module requires doing it by traversing lists only and not by implementing dictionary. Just a small thing, there is a specific test case :

Comment: I can't see the test case, could you maybe edit it in your original post?

Comment: **reqd_quantity-[2, 1, 3],price_list-[4392, 1342, 8734, 6421],gems_list-['Amber', 'Aquamarine', 'Opal', 'Topaz'],reqd_gems-['Amber', 'Opal', 'Topaz']** which is not getting matched with the system provided expected test case. And the actual output this code providing on this specific test case is : 36781

Comment: also the system is not providing it's expected result for this test case, just showing it is wrong.

Comment: yes there are 7 logical test cases and 1 structural test case, it passed all except this logical one.

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot about the discount. One second. That will teach me too read the  question too quickly.

Comment: Yes it worked now. It was the discount actually. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution and the logic:

**Explanation:** Create a dictionary of your gems and the corresponding price in the function using `dict(zip())`. Then loop over the required gems and get the corresponding value/price of that gem and multiply it with the quantity. To get the quantity from the list, I used enumerate to get access to the corresponding index.

Keep adding this into `bill_amount` inside the for loop and return outside the for loop

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
    bill_amount=0
    d = dict(zip(gems_list, price_list))
    for i, gem in enumerate(reqd_gems):
        bill_amount += d[gem]*reqd_quantity[i]

    return bill_amount

bill_amount=calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity)
print(bill_amount)
# 71945
```

Comment: `try ... except KeyError: return -1`

Comment: Did you miss the part in the first line where OP said "This is a homework problem. I am just asking about the method to solve this, not the entire solution"?

Comment: I think they did. He's being generous

Comment: @Jaba: You are right. I answered from a broader perspective for potential future readers of this post.

Comment: Lol, I would have done the same and coded it too. Easiest way to answer it to me. Python basically is pseudo code anyway..

Comment: Just unindent that code and nobody would know the difference =D

Comment: @Jaba: What do you mean? Know the difference from what?

Comment: I was joking haha, poking fun at python being "executable pseudocode"

Comment: @Bazingaa, I tried doing this way also and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Bazingaa's answer, I'm recommending that you use a mapping (Python `dict`) for this job.

First, you can create the "Gem to price" mapping like this:

```
price_map = {}  # This is an empty dict
for i in range(len(gems_list)):
    price_map[gems_list[i]] = price_list[i]
```

Then, for each gem that the custom wants, you can check if it's in stock:

```
wanted = "Invalid"
has_gem = wanted in price_map
#         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You'll be able to handle the exception that the wanted gem is invalid then.

You can fetch the price with a dictionary lookup:

```
wanted = "Ruby"
price = price_map[wanted]  # this will fetch 3920
```

---

If you understand advanced techniques like list comprehensions, dict comprehensions, value unpacking and the built-in `zip` method, then it's great and you'll be able to write shorter programs:

```
price_map = {gem: price for gem, price in zip(gems_list, price_list)}
```

And as well, if you understand Python's exception handling, you can use a `try ... except ...` block to handle the case where the required gem is invalid, without having to validate them beforehand.

```
try:
    bill_amount += quantity * price_map[gem]
except KeyError:
    # One of the gems isn't available
    return -1
```

If you want the direct solution, the just read [Bazingaa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886110/5958455).

Comment: Thanks for explaining in a nice way. I went through both @Bazingaa's post and yours and combined them to get the final results.